# Jenkins: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new Jenkins users and I receive the follow error `ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'`, I read some posts about this error here at Stack, some of them says about "capacity disk" in `/tmp`, others says about workspace default, but none of them is help me to solve that.

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/not-show-my-url.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:996)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1237)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1297)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/thiagolmoraes/Mobile-Contrato.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/not-show-my-url.git'
```

What is funny, if I use a Freestyle project, add git repository with the same credentials that I use above in Pipeline Project, I got to clone the project, so I think authentication is not the problem.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get clean

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY src /app/src

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {nodejs "node" }
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/not-show-my-url.git'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
       steps {
         sh 'npm install'
       }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credentials are indeed the issue, you need to add the credentials id to your git pipeline step like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {nodejs "node" }
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git url: 'https://github.com/not-show-my-url.git',
            credentialsId: 'your-credentials-id'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
       steps {
         sh 'npm install'
       }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The credentialsId can be obtained from http://yourjenkinsinstall/credentials.

Comment: Thanks bro, help a lot! But a question, as @huytmb post bellow, I did it too, so why wasnt work? need explicitly add credential Id?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the credentials and then, using for config pipline job:

[image]